# C# SendKeys в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

1. Как переписать для WPF?
2. Как отправлять команды нужному мне приложению?

   ```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Thread.Sleep(2000);
       SendKeys.Send("{F5}");
   }
   ```

пробовал так - не пашет:

```
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        SendKeys.Send(Key.F5);
    }
}
public static class SendKeys
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Sends the specified key.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    public static void Send(Key key)
    {
        if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice != null)
        {
            if (Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource != null)
            {
                var leGo = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, key) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
                InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(leGo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно не пашет?

Comment: меня интересует аналог SendKeys в WPF и как отправлять команду нужному приложению

Comment: Если маршалить умеете, то можно вот это использовать.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx